# What are the drawbacks to formatting a receipt in html/css and then sending it to a thermal receipt printer?

Tags: javascript, html, printing, thermal-printer

I have seen many posts on here that talk about trying to send raw zpl/epl or another printer language from a web application to a thermal printer, but most of the solutions seem like too much work for poor functionality. If you were to just format the receipt in html/css and then use javascripts window.print, wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: I guess it all comes down to your printer drivers and how you set up your print.css and browser. But it should work fine. Long time ago I created an app with PHP that sends a PNG to be printed - the results were ok. It just took a few seconds longer to print

Comment: Most thermal printers don't work like regular printers. If you wanted to print using a desktop printer, that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

You can send html/css formatted content to a receipt printer using a proper printerdiver. You will not be able to tap into the buildin fonts in the printer however. So printing native fonts and using special fonts for paper cutting and kicking drawers won't be possible.